# I connected a MySQL database to Django, but the user information is not being retrieved

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, mysql-python

```
class Review(models.Model):
    review_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    review_content = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    review_grade = models.FloatField()
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    book_isbn = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       
        db_table = 'review'


class User(models.Model):

    user_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=32)
    nickname = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=32)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_role = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.IntegerField()
    prefer_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'user'
```

"This is the code written in models.py."

```
>>> User.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> Review.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Review: Review object (1)>, <Review: Review object (2)>, <Review: Review object (3)>, <Review: Review object (4)>]>
```

"This is what I tried in the Django shell_plus. Although there is data in the database, I can't figure out why the User data returns an empty queryset. Please help me."

"I ran python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate. I also tried to find information about Django custom user model, but I couldn't solve the issue."

Comment: "Wow, when I changed the model name to 'Userr', it was able to retrieve data properly."